# MSSQL How to create a DB User only when the database is available

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I am on SQL Server and want to create a script that creates a database user in different databases, but I do not know which databases are available at runtime. I just want to skip user creation if a database is not available.
I came up with this code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE NAME = 'MyDB')
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyDB.sys.database_principals WHERE NAME = 'XUser')
    BEGIN
        /* This fails when DB MyDB is not available, despite it should not run at all */
        USE MyDB

        SELECT 'Creating User ''XUser''.'
        CREATE user XUser
        FROM LOGIN XUser
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'User ''XUser'' in MyDB already exists, skipping creation.'
    END
    SELECT 'User ''XUser'' gets special user role in MyDB database.'
    EXEC MyDB..sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'SpecialUser'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Warning: DB MyDB not found. Login ''XUser'' doesn''t get additional rights on that database.'
END
```

But it is not working, I get

```
Database 'MyDB' does not exist.
```

the USE statement seem to be the problem, but without it the user will not be created in the right db?

How can I achive what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a deferred statement here. Even though the `USE` statement won't be reached if the database doesn't exist, the database still needs to exist, otherwise the parser will detect the invalid database name and the statement will fail:

```sql
    PRINT N'Creating User ''XUser''.';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'USE MyDB; CREATE USER XUser FROM LOGIN XUser;';
```

Also, don't use `sp_addrolemember`, it's been deprecated for at least 13 years; use `ALTER ROLE`.